# RSpec loop testing with console input and output

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have an **input** method, that intended to read circle radius from console. If input is invalid, method outputs error message and loops to read input again.

So I need to make an rspec test that iterates by array of invalid inputs and expect that
**input** method will output error to console message each time.

Here is my **input** class:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require_relative '../data/messages'

# Input class is responsible for reading and writing to and from console and
# querying user
class Input
  def read
    loop do
      print "#{RADIUS_QUERY_MSG}\n> "
      radius = gets.strip
      return radius.to_f if valid?(radius)

      puts INVALID_MSG
    end
  end

  private

  def valid?(radius)
    /\A[+]?\d+(\.\d+)?\z/.match(radius)
  end
end
```

I've tried this in my rspec test, but it seems to get into some infinite loop:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'input'
require_relative '../data/messages'
require_relative '../data/rspec'

RSpec.describe Input do
  let(:input) { described_class.new }

  describe '#read' do
    INVALID_INPUTS.each do |invalid_input|
      context "with invalid input \"#{invalid_input}\"" do
        it 'tells user that input is invalid' do
          allow(input).to receive(:gets).and_return(invalid_input)
          expect(input.read).to output("#{INVALID_MSG}\n").to_stdout
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I do this properly? Would appreciate any help.

*P.S.*
Found this article, but it was no use for me. Maybe it will help. https://haughtcodeworks.com/blog/software-development/easy-loop-testing/

*P.P.S.*
`INVALID_MSG` and `RADIUS_QUERY_MSG`  are strings and `INVALID_INPUTS` is an array of strings.

Comment: Feels like the test is getting locked in the `gets` loop because you `puts` the error, but you never return from that function if things are invalid.  I wonder if you could pull out the code inside the loop - test that directly and don't test the fact that it goes in an never ending loop (when there is an error case).  Interesting little problem.

Comment: Don't set expectations using stubs/mocks like this if you can avoid it. Instead, refactor your class or method to accept test data. Otherwise, you're just putting more effort coding tests than testing code. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Refactor to Inject Your Test Inputs into the "Real" Method

This is a common problem for code that isn't written test-first. There are a couple of ways to solve it, but the simplest option without mocking, stubbing, or otherwise invalidating your "real" code is simply to refactor the method itself. For example:

```rb
def read test_input: nil
  loop do
    print "#{RADIUS_QUERY_MSG}\n> "
    radius = (test_input || gets).strip
    return radius.to_f if valid?(radius)

    puts INVALID_MSG
  end
end
```

Now you can simply inject whatever values you want into the optional *test_input* keyword argument from your RSpec tests to ensure that the input is stripped properly and exhibits whatever other behavior you're testing for.

This avoids all sorts of problems you might experience by trying to write around a difficult-to-test method. Either you provide test input directly to the method, in which case the method uses that, or you don't, in which case it calls #gets just as it normally would.

Remember, the goal isn't to test core methods like #gets. Instead, you should be testing the *behavior* of your method or object given a particular input or state. If you make your methods testable by allowing dependency injection in your code, or refactoring your class to allow modifying instance variables in your test setup and using those rather than method arguments passed to your methods, you ensure that you are testing your *real* class or method rather than hacking your way around it.

There are certainly other, more complex ways to do what I did above, but they don't seem warranted for this specific example. The KISS principle definitely applies!

Comment: Thx for the awesome answer and a little inside on how to test :)

*P. S.* I will give up on loop altogether, I guess, and just throw an exception.